# why do we need the pluginSetup address and the pluginSetupRepo when deploying an aragonOSx plugin?

Tags: contract-deployment

why do you need to pass both the pluginSetup address and the pluginSetupRepo? the repo contains the latest and previous versions, whats the rationale or im i misunderstanding how those work?

they all have ens names, but still I can't seem to work out how to search for these.

for a bit of context on what Im doing, I'm building a boilerplate with some helper tasks app developers will need. Things like `apm:deploy` and `apm:bump:minor`, etc. Of course, I don't want to rely on saving the repo address locally, users should be able to specify their app name.

Answer (score 0):

the `pluginSetup` address is the contract containing the instructions on how to install that specific plugin to a given DAO, whereas the `pluginSetupRepo` is the repository containing all of the addresses of every version of a `pluginSetup` contract.
This means that - the `pluginSetupRepo` is a container of addresses of `pluginSetup` contracts, each of which refers to a specific plugin version.

The `PluginSetupRepo` acts as a means of indexing what specific plugin and what version you are installing.

The `PluginSetupRepo`'s contract address will be linked to an ENS, so that you will know that you are in fact installing a given plugin, say `erc20-voting.plugin.eth`
The `pluginSetup` address is the way of specifying what "version" of the plugin you want to use. It's the equivalent of doing `npm install react@17`.

This is the low level implementation, unless you're integrating from within Solidity, you should be using Aragon's JS SDK, which you can find here (https://github.com/aragon/sdk)